# Class-level generic constraint on interface in Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript

What is causing this code to fail?

```
interface ISomeData {
    name: string;
}

class SomeData implements ISomeData {
    name: string = "adam";
}

class SomeClass<T extends ISomeData> {
    constructor(dataTemplate?: T) {
        this.dataTemplateInternal = dataTemplate;
    }

    private dataTemplateInternal: T;

    public initSomeData() : T {
        let data: T = new SomeData();
        if (this.dataTemplateInternal) {
            return this.dataTemplateInternal;
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

The first line of "initSomeData" has an error saying

> Type 'SomeData' is not assignable to type 'T'

But since my generic constraint is based on an interface, which SomeData implements, shouldn't that be sufficient?

[Ridiculously long link to this code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ISomeData%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SomeData%20implements%20ISomeData%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22adam%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SomeClass%3CT%20extends%20ISomeData%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(dataTemplate%3F%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.dataTemplateInternal%20%3D%20dataTemplate%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20dataTemplateInternal%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20initSomeData()%20%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20data%3A%20T%20%3D%20new%20SomeData()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.dataTemplateInternal)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.dataTemplateInternal%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20data%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd do:

```
let data: ISomeData = new SomeData();
```

You wouldn't get this error, but `T` is not `ISomeData`, it is something "more" than `ISomeData`, for example it can be:

```
interface IMoreData extends ISomeData {
    username: string;
}
```

And then you say that:

```
let data: IMoreData = new SomeData();
```

Which isn't right as it's missing the `username` property.
You can solve this by telling the compiler that you know what you're doing (AKA casting):

```
let data: T = new SomeData() as T;
```

Or just:

```
let data = new SomeData() as T;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it!  I was kinda thinking that's what I needed to do, not sure why I didn't just try it!

Comment: Just as a side-question, isn't the constraint stating that "your implementation must be a minimum of [THIS]" (in my case `interface ISomeData { name: string }`) and isn't implementing that Interface assuring that it has "name: string"?  I still don't quite understand why it doesn't implicitly understand my intent there. Is that by design, or like a "todo" in the language spec? :) Nevertheless, you rock, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the generic constraint assure that `name` exists in `T`, **but** `T` **isn't**  `ISomeData` so the compiler warns you about it. If you have an instance of `SomeClass<IMoreData>` then the result of `initSomeData` should be of type `IMoreData` and not `ISomeData`